# How do I disable GPG signing for `git rebase --continue`?

Tags: git, rebase, gnupg

I am attempting to rebase a branch. My GPG/SSH agent setup is broken - `git rebase --continue` attempts to sign the commit and fails.

I have done everything I can think of to disable GPG and nothing is working. `git rebase --continue --no-gpg-sign` prints out rebase's help message, and changing config files and/or adding `-c commit.gpgSign=false` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart the rebase:

1. `git rebase --abort` to cancel the current rebase.
2. Run the rebase again, **adding `--no-gpg-sign` this time.**
3. Resolve conflicts, etc.
4. `git rebase --continue` works now.

Evidently GPG/SSH settings are 'locked in' by the initial rebase command and subsequent rebase operations (or at least `git rebase --continue`) do not respect configuration changes - they are locked into the settings used for the initial rebase.